# SQL to MapReduce: how sql avg function could be done in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

How could write the sql avg function in MapReduce MongoDB?
I've tried the following, sum the values and divide for a count. But the problem is where i do  it, in reduce function or finalize function?

For example:
i have the following document

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("511b7d1b3daee1b1446ecdfe"),
  "l_linenumber" : 1,
  "l_quantity" : 17,
  "l_extendedprice" : 21168.23,
  "l_discount" : 0.04,
  "l_tax" : 0.02,
  "l_returnflag" : "N",
  "l_linestatus" : "O",
  "l_shipdate" : ISODate("1996-03-13T03:00:00Z"),
  "l_commitdate" : ISODate("1996-02-12T03:00:00Z"),
  "l_receiptdate" : ISODate("1996-03-22T03:00:00Z"),
  "l_shipinstruct" : "DELIVER IN PERSON",
  "l_shipmode" : "TRUCK",
  "l_comment" : "blithely regular ideas caj",
}
```

And the SQL query is:

```
select
    l_returnflag, 
    l_linestatus, 
    sum(l_quantity) as sum_qty,
    sum(l_extendedprice) as sum_base_price,
    sum(l_extendedprice*(1-l_discount)) as sum_disc_price,
    sum(l_extendedprice*(1-l_discount)*(1+l_tax)) as sum_charge,
    avg(l_quantity) as avg_qty, 
    avg(l_extendedprice) as avg_price,
    avg(l_discount) as avg_disc, 
    count(*) as count_order
from 
    lineitem
where 
    l_shipdate <= DATE_SUB('1998-12-01',INTERVAL 90 DAY)
group by 
    l_returnflag, 
    l_linestatus
order by 
    l_returnflag, 
    l_linestatus;
```

I done this mapreduce function:

```
db.runCommand({
    mapreduce: "lineitem",
    map: function Map() {
            var dataInicial = new Date("Dec 1, 1998");
            var dataFinal = new Date();
            dataFinal.setDate(dataInicial.getDate()-90);
                if( this.l_shipdate<=dataFinal) {
                    emit(
                        {returnflag: this.l_returnflag, linestatus: this.l_linestatus}, 
                        {
                            sum_qty: this.l_quantity,
                            sum_base_price: this.l_extendedprice,
                            sum_disc_price: this.l_extendedprice*(1-this.l_discount),
                            sum_charge: this.l_extendedprice*(1-this.l_discount)*(1+this.l_tax),
                            avg_qty: this.l_quantity,
                            avg_price: this.l_extendedprice,
                            avg_disc: this.l_discount,
                            count_order: 1
                        }
                    );
                }
        },
    reduce: function(key, values) {
                var ret = {sum_qty: 0, sum_base_price: 0, sum_disc_price: 0, sum_charge: 0, 
                            avg_qty: 0, avg_price: 0, avg_disc: 0, count_order: 0};
                for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    ret.sum_qty += values[i].sum_qty;
                    ret.sum_base_price += values[i].sum_base_price;
                    ret.sum_disc_price += values[i].sum_disc_price;
                    ret.sum_charge += values[i].sum_charge;
                    ret.avg_qty += values[i].avg_qty;
                    ret.avg_price += values[i].avg_price;
                    ret.avg_disc += values[i].avg_disc;
                    ret.count_order += values[i].count_order;
                }
                return ret;
            },
finalize: function(key, value) {
                value.avg_qty = value.avg_qty/value.count_order;
                value.avg_price = value.avg_qty/value.count_order;
                value.avg_disc = value.avg_qty/value.count_order;
            return value;
        },
    out: 'query001'
});
```

The answer for avg_qty, avg_price, avg_disc are incorrect. Whats is going on? Or the sum and divide by count would be done inside reduce function?

Comment: The reduce can run multiple times which means that your average will be off, so every 101 results MongoDB will actually send in the average you have which you will calc a new average from which will make it incorrect. You could do this with the aggregation framework

Comment: No way to do it in MapReduce then?

Comment: You can, you can do this in the finalize function which will only ever run once, however, the aggregation framework could be easier here so I suggested it.

Comment: but in my case i run in finalize function, but the answer its wrong. why?

Comment: Nah your only running a reduce there, there is a third function, `finalize()`

Comment: excuse me i forgot it. does it seems like that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it with MapReduce:

```
m = function (){
  emit( {returnflag: this.l_returnflag, linestatus: this.l_linestatus} , 
        { sum_base_price: this.l_extendedprice, count : 1 } );
};

r = function (name, values){
  var res = {sum_base_price : 0, count : 0};
  values.forEach (function (v) {
    res.sum_base_price += v[i].sum_base_price;
    res.count += v[i].count;
  }
  return res;
};

f = function(key, res){
  res.avg = res.sum_base_price / res.count;
  return res;
};
```

Then, call mapReduce:

```
db.lineitem.mapReduce( m, r, 
                   { finalize : f, 
                     out : {inline : 1}, 
                     query: {l_shipdate:{$lt:dataFinal}} 
                   }
);
```

So you are not filtering in the map function, you are doing it in a query before calling map (that's more efficient).

In aggregation framework it would be:

```
db.lineitem.aggregate( [
   {$match: {l_shipdate:{$lt:dataFinal}},
   {$group: { _id: {returnflag: "$l_returnflag", linestatus: "$l_linestatus"},
              sum_base_price: {$sum:"$l_extended_price"},
              avg_base_price: {$avg:"$l_extended_price"},
              count: {$sum: 1}
            }
   }
])
```

Add your other fields as needed...